# Carregar arquivo HTML dentro de outro arquivo HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicação-web

Eu tenho um arquivo **index.html**:

```
<body>
    <div class="application">
        <header class="header"></header>
        <main class="content"></main>
        <footer class="footer"></footer>
    </div>
    <script src="script/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

E tenho o **header**, o **main** e o **footer** em pastas separadas.
Gostaria de saber como posso adicionar esses arquivos externos dentro desse arquivo principal, assim que a página for carregada.
Estou tentando criar de forma mais pura possível (usando somente HTML, CSS e JS, evitando frameworks). Mas se só for possível com alguma biblioteca, eu posso incluir.

Comment: Faz um include com PHP https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273072/carregar-html-de-outro-html/273090#273090 apenas com HTML isso pode te dar uma luz https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281023/que-recurso-encontro-em-html-como-op%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ao-include-do-php/281044#281044 e com JS vc pode salvar seu .html da outra pasta como um .JS e na sua página vc faz o append desse script como o template do html dentro algo do tipo

Answer (score 2):

Com o **Jquery**

Arquivo template.html

```
<head>
<!--Carrega a biblioteca via CDN. Se vc já carrega outra dentro do seu projeto não precisa-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(function(){
$('#header').load("nome-arquivo-header.html");
$('#body').load("nome-arquivo-body.html");
$('#footer').load("nome-arquivo-footer.html");
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Cara, valeu mesmo, funcionou aqui! Agradeço de verdade.